# objective c demo using core data, but crash. It works with swift

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I am new to Core Data. I started a demo project with Xcode 8 by using objective-c and make sure the using-core-data checkbox checked. Then I added the model to scheme, tried to insert a model to core data context. I got a result of crash, however, the same implementation is fine in Swift. Any help?

STEP: (Xcode 8 + iOS 10)

1. Launch Xcode 8, create a new app, use objective-c and use core-data.
2. Add an Entity in .xcdatamodeld file. I named it "Entity". Make sure this Entity is in "Current Product Module" and NOT use Codegen from Xcode.
3. Create a NSManagedObject subclass and name it as same as "Entity".
4. In ViewController class, use context to insert one of Entity object in viewDidLoad.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] persistentContainer] viewContext];

    Entity *entity = [[Entity alloc] initWithContext:context];
    entity.attribute = @"hello";
}
```

And it crashes. It seems like the core data is not generating proper NSManagedObject subclass.

I also put the demo here to let you know that I really didn't do anything else. https://github.com/huang-kun/CoreDataTemplate.git

Comment: Please post a precise technical question. This is not the place to review your entire project.

Comment: OK, I change the post and add the steps.

Answer (score 0):

## The module is the problem.

remove it and set it to 'empty' > global namespace

ObjC doesnt know modules and the name mangling gets wrong (I guess)

Comment: Thank you, I just got the idea. haha.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figure it myself. There is a different configuration between objc and swift project in core data entity.

- Use "Current Product Module" for entity in swift
- Use nothing or "Global namespace" for entity in objc

Because "AppName.Entity" class is not found in objc and only "Entity", which uses global namespace, can be found correctly!

I made a mistake by using swift configuration for objc project.